# overlapping bootstrap modals not hiding modal-background

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal which is called every time text, which is feed from a RFID scanner,  is entered into a textbox. The some logic is done at backcode and the modal is shown using ScriptManager. There's no problem when an ID is scanned after the modal and background have faded-out. There are of course instances when an ID is read twice in quick succession. This causes another modal and background to be called. The modal fades out properly but it leaves it's background still being displayed.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could suggest a fix or work around to this :)

Comment: why dont u make 1st Modal hide on 2nd Modal Loading...(use javascript for for hiding 1st Modal)

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that? Lol got used to ajaxtoolkit handling my modals.